# Gitlab CI - How to skip job if cache exists

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I have a `setup` job in my CI which installs all npm packages and stores them in cache:

```yaml
setup:
  stage: pre-build
  cache:
    untracked: true
    when: on_success
    key:
      files:
        - repo-hash
      prefix: workspace
  script:
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

Currently, if the repo-hash does not change between two pipelines, the job successfully downloads the existing cache, but it still runs `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`.

How to change this behaviour, so that if the cache exists, this job is skipped?

Comment: You should cache the `.yarn` directory, per e.g. https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install-ci/; you still need to do the install, but then most (if not all) of the files are already local.

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't mind the downloading step, it is mainly the `yarn install` step which I'd like to skip :/

Comment: Did you find a way of doing this ? Skipping the yarn install step ?

Comment: We finally decided not to do it. However I think you can use the `changes` keyword of gitlab-ci.yml to run the job only if the specified field has changed: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Answer (score 12):

Right now on an NPM-based Preact project, I'm using gitlab-ci.yml's `only` feature to run an install job if there was any change to package-lock.json (and to skip install if not). Then my build job picks up the node_modules cache from the install job:

```yaml
install:
  stage: setup # gitlab.com shared runners are slow; don't run unless there's a reason to install
  cache:       # even a "echo 'hello world'" script would be about a 30s job, worse if queued
    key:
      files: [package-lock.json] # the key is a hash of package-lock; branches with it will use this cache :D
    paths: [node_modules] # we're not caching npm (ie `npm ci --prefer-offline --cache`) because it's slow
    policy: push # override the default behavior of wasting time downloading and unpacking node_modules
  script: [npm ci] # I believe in package-lock/npm ci's mission
  only:
    changes: [package-lock.json] # our forementioned reason to install
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
      - merge_requests

build: # uses the default behavior, which runs even if install is skipped; but not if install failed
  stage: build
  cache:
    key:
      files: [package-lock.json]
    paths: [node_modules]
    policy: pull # override the default behavior of wasting time packing and uploading node_modules
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths: [build]
  only:
    changes:
      - src/**/*
      - tsconfig.json
      - preact.config.js
      - package-lock.json
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
      - merge_requests
```

For Yarn you would simply replace any `package-lock.json` you see here with `yarn.lock`, and replace `npm ci` with `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`.

Previously, I was doing it all in the build job like this (similar to one of the other answers here):

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key:
      files: [package-lock.json]
    paths: [node_modules]
  script:
    - test -d node_modules || npm ci
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths: [build]
  only:
    changes:
      - src/**/*
      - tsconfig.json
      - preact.config.js
      - package-lock.json
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
      - merge_requests
```

I changed to the more complicated approach because I thought I was also going to implement caching for npm cache, but I couldn't seem to get that to improve any actual install times -- things actually got worse. I stuck with it though simply because it allowed me to squeeze another 20 seconds out of the lockfile-wasn't-changed scenario. I find both approaches to be valid and effective. In my specific case, caching node_modules has cut about a minute and a half off of deployments.

Answer (score 9):

try exit?

```
install:
  stage: install
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
      prefix: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - |
      if [[ -d node_modules ]]; then
        exit 10
      fi
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes: 10
```

Comment: It would be better to just change 10 error code to 0

Comment: This will work, but it would be better if that was possible at Gitlab level, because it can take a while to spin up the job (exemple: Docker executor on not super powerfull Windows VM takes 1 minute to reach this exit).

Answer (score 3):

As per the official reference, this is not possible on the job level. However, you can add conditions to your job scripts and check for the existence of the should-be-cached files.

This is what the relevant parts of my setup look like:

```yaml
stages:
- setup
- test
- build
- release
- publish

cache: &dependency-cache
  key:
    files:
    - "**/yarn.lock"
  paths:
  - node_modules
  - "*/node_modules"
  policy: pull

renew-cache:
  stage: setup
  except:
  - /master.*/
  - tags
  script:
  - test -d node_modules || yarn && yarn workspace app ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main
  cache:
    <<: *dependency-cache
    policy: pull-push

test-app:
  stage: test
  except:
  - /master.*/
  - tags
  script:
  - test -d node_modules || yarn
  - yarn workspace app test

build-app:
  stage: build
  only:
  - /master.*/
  script:
  - test -d node_modules || yarn
  - yarn workspace app build
  # Store build results ...

# The rest of the pipeline
```

- I use yarn 2+ and yarn workspaces with `node-modules` yarn linker and `dependency` module hoisting limit
- The cache is shared for all jobs with `pull` policy, the `renew-cache` job is the only one to write the cache
- `test -d node_modules || <COMMAND>` runs the `<COMMAND>` only if the `node_modules` directory was not found - no cache for the job
- New cache is pushed only when there is none or when any `yarn.lock` is modified
- The same cache is re-used until it expires and while the `yarn.lock` files do not change
- The test for the cached `node_modules` has to be present in all other build scripts that rely on the cache - the cache could have expired and the pipeline must be deterministically repeatable

This approach does not eliminate the need to run the setup job every time, so there is still some overhead. However, the overall pipeline run times are reduced greatly.

Hope this helps a little :-)